# nHibernate Doesn't update other table through Oracle Package in same session

Tags: c#, nhibernate

In a window application we are using nHibernate. We are facing problem when updating data a table (Tag1 or Tag2) and in the same ISession we are inserting data from the table  into another table (QA Table) using Oracle Package. On commit Oracle package doesnt't see the changed data in the Tag1/Tag2 table hence the modified data is not updated in QA table, might be becuase being called in the same session?

```
    using (ISession session = iNhibernet.OpenSession())
            {

                using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {

                    try
                    {
                        // Business Entity Saved in Tag1/Tag2 Table
                        session.SaveOrUpdate(l);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        ErrorLogExceptionHandler.ErrorLog(ref ex);
                        throw new Exception("Unable to save data");
                    }
                    // Calling Oracle Package to Compare Tag1 and Tag2 data and inserting data in QA Table.
                    IDbCommand db = ProductionLog.ProductionLogUpdate(l.ProductionlogSeqNo, loadAction) as DbCommand;
                    db.Connection = session.Connection;
                    try
                    {
                        db.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        ErrorLogExceptionHandler.ErrorLog(ref ex);
                        throw new Exception("Unable to insert in production log");
                    }
                transaction.Commit();
       }
    }
```

Can some help.

Thanks,

Comment: Where did "l" come from? Did it come from the same session that you're using to call "SaveOrUpdate"?

Comment: "l" is an business entity we are saving with "session.SaveOrUpdate(l);" and later on in the same session we are calling a oracle package  "IDbCommand db = ProductionLog.ProductionLogUpdate(l.ProductionlogSeqNo, loadAction) as DbCommand" to move data into QA tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling

```
                    session.SaveOrUpdate(l);
```

but this does not force the session to instantly update the database. 
NHibernate minimises calls to the database by storing all pending updates, and then calling them on the database in one batch. The `SaveOrUpdate` invocation is instructing the session to update the database with changes to `l` on the next `Flush` or `Commit`.

The oracle command is expecting the data to have already been written to the database.

I believe you can solve this problem with an explict call to `Flush`.

```
            using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {

                try
                {
                    // Business Entity Saved in Tag1/Tag2 Table
                    session.SaveOrUpdate(l);
                    session.Flush();  // <<== Write all of our changes so far
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ErrorLogExceptionHandler.ErrorLog(ref ex);
                    throw new Exception("Unable to save data");
                }
```